# how to use scrollviews in android

Tags: android-layout, android-scrollview

I am creating an app which requires ScrollViews and i am getting trouble using them. When i added the scrollview the layout of the app shifted upwards and i dont know what is the problem. How can i get rid of this problem?
The screenshot of before and after i added the scrollview is below [Before Scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE1Fj.png) & [After Scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4INO0.png)

**Below is the code after scrollview**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="24dp"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/city_image_view"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_36dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/city_image_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="@string/select_city"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/city_text_view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/city_text_view"
        android:layout_below="@id/city_text_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/city_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/city_text_view"
        android:layout_below="@id/city_spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/send_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` property to your scroll view. It will help you to get perfect layout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!--Enter your code here-->

</ScrollView>
```